# Why is loop iterating one extra time?

Tags: java

```
int b=1,a=0,c;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
do {
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println(c);

    a=b;
    b=c;
}while(c<=1000 );
```

The results are the following:

0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597

Can someone explain how does 1597 being printed even though the condition has to be <=1000?

Comment: Because `c` is printed in between `c=a+b` and `while (c<=1000)`.

Comment: Title of this question had almost nothing to do with question/problem you ware asking about. Please see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647).

Answer (score 3):

> how does 1597 being printed even though the condition has to be <=1000?

Because `c` is printed in between `c=a+b` and `while (c<=1000)`.

Change the condition to, for example:

```
while(a+b<=1000 );
```